# Context aware localization

Tags: laravel, localization

I have this code:

[image: Localization code snippet]

and I want laravel to return **"Search"** if I use:

```
@lang('messages.search')
```

and **"Search for title, description or code"** if I use:

```
@lang('messages.search.placeholder')
```

Is there any way to do this or anything similar? Or do I have to use a different name for the **"Search"** string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible, since you are declaring twice the search value and it would always take the last defined value, what you could do is something like this:

```
'search' => [
    '' => 'Search',
    'placeholder' => 'Search for title, description or code'
]
```

And use it like `@lang('messages.search.')` check for the last dot cause it would be needed.

Although a more common approach would be to set a name for the first key pair:

```
'search' => [
    'title' => 'Search',
    'placeholder' => 'Search for title, description or code'
]
```

And use them as: `@lang('messages.search.title')` and `@lang('messages.search.placeholder')`